# Strange behaviour using serial port and bluetooth

Tags: linux, linux-mint, serial-port, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect via serial port, a wearable device to a processing IDE using a Bluetooth connection on Linux Mint. I've got the connection part working, but the problem is that the connection is not reliable and is slow. However, executing the same program code in Windows and Mac, everything works smooth and fine.

What do I mean with "the connection is not reliable and is slow?

To "talk" with the wearable device, I need to send packets, bytes, (to get its sample rate, to start streaming, etc). If I just send a request for something, I usually get nothing, so I have to send it twice or three times before the device answers me.

Also, if the device is streaming, sometimes I get packets (bytes) in a different order and weird stuff like this. As I said, in Windows and Mac all this does not happen.

I don't know a lot about ports but it seems there is some problem with these. After pairing my device using the Linux GUI, I run the following commands (as administrator) on my terminal to start the connection:

```
$ hcitool scan -> to scan BT devices
$ rfcomm bind 0 00:06:66:42:10:44 -> To connect the Shimmer
$ ./processing
```

Once this is done, if I use the command rfcomm I get:

```
$ rfcomm
rfcomm0: 00:06:66:42:10:44 channel 1 clean
```